# What's the recommended virtual machine on a Mac?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine

I used to use qemu on linux,

but it seems [not functioning well on osx](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/886621),

any alternatives?

Comment: You need to explain what virtualization solutions you've already found and why they didn't work for you. I can't imagine there isn't enough reading material on the web already.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking to game on Mac - use [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/). Hands down it has the fastest 3D-acceleration virtualization on Mac.

If you need to run productivity apps mainly, then go with [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html) for its outstanding support and configuration tool, as well as superior OpenGL and productivity benchmarks.

If you would prefer free, then go with [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

For a comprehensive review, you can read this article on [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2011/10/virtual-showdown-parallels-desktop-7-and-vmware-fusion-4-reviewed.ars).

I personally prefer VMWare, as it has a long history of outstanding virtualization products, and productivity performance is more important to me.

Comment: Note that VMWare Fusion 4 claims to be time machine friendly,  Fusion 3 is not (unless you have your virtual machine in a sparse image)

Answer (score 1):

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) is currently the best free one.  Commercially, in general VMWare has slightly better guest compatibility whereas Parallels is slightly faster — but you should probably ask a search engine about the specific hypervisor and guest OS you want to use, to see if there are any known issues.